# Crontab, python script fails to run

Tags: python, bash, unix, cron

I have a bash script to automate few things I do. The bash calls 2 python scripts, If I run the bash script normally, everything runs, no errors what so ever. I set up a cron job to Automate this and when I checked the logs I noticed the python scripts don't run at all. It gives me the following error.

`python: can't open file 'movefiles.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

`python: can't open file 'create_log_shimmer.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Both these files exist and runs when calling the bash script directly.

Comment: In cron jobs, always use absolute (complete) path names, not relative ones.  You might also need to update (source) your environment, for example `. $HOME/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The working directory of the cron is different from the directory you run the script directly.

- Make your bash script to use absolute path for python script files.
- Or make the bash script to change directory to where you run the script directly.

Comment: Thanks, I used absolute path for the python scripts and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:
**1) Crontab default path is somewhere else**

**2) IN python .py file you haven't mentioned the complete file names with in the code [in case you used]**

**3) Specify the complete path in the cron file while running **

BELOW SHOWS THE BEST TO CREATE THE CRON (NOT THE BEST BUT FOR ME ITS EASY AS"

Best way to have a cronjob (crontab is )

1) create a file in that directory by 
vi FILENAME.cron

2) in the filename type in the following (This sets the current path to be the cron path)

```
# echo PATH=$PATH > tmp.cron
# echo >> tmp.cron
# crontab -l >> tmp.cron
# crontab tmp.cron

* * * * * python ___________.py
```

3) Now keep in mind that save it and to start the cron type
crontab FILENAME.cron. ( In you python .py code, if you are accessing any file or writtin to a file or database provide the full path in that place)

4) You would be able to run the cron with ease.